# How does re-assigning a reference work in a method?

Tags: java, methods, reference, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a linked list using objects of class "ListNode"

ListNode has the following non static methods:

```
getValue()
setValue(Object obj)
getNext()
setNext(ListNode ln)
```

It's constructor takes a value and a next.

In my main method in my driver class, create my linked list:

```
ListNode head = new ListNode("Overflow!", null);
head = new ListNode("Stack", head);
head = new ListNode("in", head);
head = new ListNode("is", head);
head = new ListNode("This", head);
```

I have a method called `printList(ListNode ln)`.

I call it twice consecutively in my main method like this:

```
printList(head);
System.out.println();
printList(head);
```

My method looks like this:

```
public static void printList(ListNode head)
{
    while(head != null)
    {
        System.out.print(head.getValue()+" ");
        head = head.getNext();
    }
}
```

In my method, the reference is changed to point to a different object each time in the while loop. So after I exit the method, the reference "head" should be pointing to a null, right? However, when the printList(head) is called the second time, it magically prints all the elements in the list!

Here is what the jGrasp console shows:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java StackOverflowQuestionExampleClass

This is in Stack Overflow! 
This is in Stack Overflow! 
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Here is the listnode class my teacher told me to use:

```
//Thomas Bettge, TJHSST, 10-20-2006
    public class ListNode
   {
      private Object value;
      private ListNode next;
       public ListNode(Object v, ListNode n)
      {
         value=v;
         next=n;
      }
       public Object getValue()
      {
         return value;
      }
       public ListNode getNext()
      {
         return next;
      }
       public void setValue(Object newv)
      {
         value=newv;
      }
       public void setNext(ListNode newn)
      {
         next=newn;
      }
   }
```

Comment: What is your question? What do you see and what do you expect to see?

Comment: A) What's your question? B) Repeatedly assigning to `head` means you'll lose access to the object previously assigned to `head`.

Comment: Hey guys I just updated my question. I accidentally hit enter while typing the tags for my question so it submitted before I typed my whole question.
@T.J. Crowder I realised that after my mishap with submitting the question. It is now fixed as I pass head to the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusion is probably stemming from the fact that you have 2 labels with the same name "head".    The "head" argument in the printList method is a new reference to the object that was passed in.  reassigning it doesn't affect the target of the original reference (in the sense that t won't cause it to reference something else.  an aside: changes to the *state* of the referenced object will have an effect, as it's the same object, regardless of what is referencing it).

might make it clearer to look at your code like this:

```
public void yourMainMethod() {
    ListNode head = new ListNode("Overflow!", null);
    head = new ListNode("Stack", head);
    head = new ListNode("in", head);
    head = new ListNode("is", head);
    head = new ListNode("This", head);

    printList(head);
    System.out.println();
    printList(head);
}

//note different name, to clarify this is a separate reference
public static void printList(ListNode node) {
    while(node != null)
    {
        System.out.print(node.getValue()+" ");
        node = node.getNext();

        //node.setValue(new Object());//note that this would change the state inside the ListNode passed in
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`head` is a local reference inside the method print.
Reassigning into it doesn't affect the `head` reference outside the method.

Comment: Not sure I agree...head is a ref and if you change it in the method, it would be changed outside of the method too...

Comment: @GregOks If you invoke a method that changes the **object** being referenced, than sure. But the reference variable **itself** is local.

Comment: I was under the impression that grek oks is correct. But maybe you are correct, dima ridnik.

Comment: This is correct. Assignment changes the local variable only, and has no visible effect outside the method.

Comment: Ok, but I said brian's was the accepted answer because it was a bit more elaborate. I still upvoted it! Thank you so much for answering!